# QT Connect used as QueuedConnection to postpone the signal emit

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I'm not very strong in Qt and I'm trying to solve a problem with signal/slots.

I have a method M0 that emits a signal Sig0 and then waits for another signal Sig1. The Sig0 calls a slot Slot0 which in turn does some work and then emits the signal Sig1.
Sometimes it happens that Slot0 performs its job and emits the signal Sig1 before the method M0 goes waiting for signal Sig1

Apparently, I solved the problem using a QueuedConnection in the connect of the signal Sig0

My question is: is it the right solution or is it just a coincidence? And if it is a coincidence could you suggest a viable solution to this problem?

Notice that M0 lives in a thread while Slot0 in the main thread